# jQuery Swipe Event does not work with jQuery 3

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-mobile

I loaded yesterday in my code jQuery Mobile because I need the Swipe Event to get some work done. The following was my script configuration (all scripts are loaded right before the *body* close tag):

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.0.0/jquery.js" type="application/javascript"></script> 

<script>window.jQuery || document.write('<script src="../js/jquery-3.0.0.min.js" type="application/javascript"><\/script>')</script>   

<script src="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.4.5/jquery.mobile-1.4.5.js"></script> 

<script type="application/javascript" src="../js/javascript.js" ></script>
```

I put the following code in *javascript.js* (the last script) just to test the new jQuery Mobile and it didn't work.

**JAVASCRIPT/JQUERY**

```
$j("body").on("swiperight", function(){
$j("#sidePanel").css("display","none"); 
});
```

At this point, I did some debugging and found that the problem was in jQuery 3; The problem does not come up if I load a previous version of jQuery (2 or 1). The following works like a charm:

```
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.2.4.js" integrity="sha256-iT6Q9iMJYuQiMWNd9lDyBUStIq/8PuOW33aOqmvFpqI=" crossorigin="anonymous" type="application/javascript"></script>

<script>window.jQuery || document.write('<script src="../js/jquery-2.2.4.js" type="application/javascript"><\/script>')</script> 

<script src="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.4.5/jquery.mobile-1.4.5.js"></script> 

<script type="application/javascript" src="../js/javascript.js" ></script>
```

**Question**: why the Swipe Event does not work with jQuery 3?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: then why use jquery 3

Answer (score 3):

jQuery mobile needs "jQuery 1.8 - 1.11 / 2.1". No jQuery 3 support at the moment.

You could use the [jQuery Migrate Plugin](https://github.com/jquery/jquery-migrate/#readme) as a workaround.

```
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.0.0.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-migrate-3.0.0.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.4.5/jquery.mobile-1.4.5.js"></script> 
<script type="application/javascript" src="../js/javascript.js" ></script>
```

Answer (score 2):

Just for swipe events I recommend this lightweight library:

`Tocca.js` (about 5kb and compatible with jquery.js 3.x) instead of jQueryMobile (about 200 Kb and NOT compatible with jquery.js 3.x).

Also, there is not need to use jQuery at all. It´s optional.

It's easy to implement and well documented. Check some examples:

[Tocca.js GitHub](https://github.com/GianlucaGuarini/Tocca.js)

[Tocca.js Developer's website](https://gianlucaguarini.com/Tocca.js/)